# How to upload a file to OCI Object storage

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-java-sdk

I am trying to use `UploadObjectExample.java` code to upload a file to OCI object storage. I am running into connection timeout error while connecting to the object storage URL. The same config file is used by OCI CLI to successfully upload files to OCI config.

Here is the Error log:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.oracle.bmc.model.BmcException: (-1, null, true) Timed out while communicating to: https://objectstorage.us-ashburn-1.oraclecloud.com (outbound opc-request-id: 1EB5AA4A7FD64D58A54F876AD0C9E83B)
    at com.oracle.bmc.http.internal.RestClient.convertToBmcException(RestClient.java:572)
    at com.oracle.bmc.http.internal.RestClient.put(RestClient.java:380)
    at com.oracle.bmc.objectstorage.ObjectStorageClient.putObject(ObjectStorageClient.java:1053)
    at com.oracle.bmc.objectstorage.transfer.internal.SimpleRetry$1.apply(SimpleRetry.java:34)
    at com.oracle.bmc.objectstorage.transfer.internal.SimpleRetry$1.apply(SimpleRetry.java:26)
    at com.oracle.bmc.objectstorage.transfer.UploadManager.singleUpload(UploadManager.java:111)
    at com.oracle.bmc.objectstorage.transfer.UploadManager.upload(UploadManager.java:73)
    at UploadObjectExample.main(UploadObjectExample.java:74)
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:278)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.lambda$invoke$0(JerseyInvocation.java:753)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:229)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:414)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:752)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:445)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.put(JerseyInvocation.java:334)
    at com.oracle.bmc.http.internal.ForwardingInvocationBuilder.put(ForwardingInvocationBuilder.java:141)
    at com.oracle.bmc.http.internal.RestClient.put(RestClient.java:377)
```

Comment: On investigating further with debugger, it seems that PutObjectRequest class is not instantiated. The error while debugging through that is 'this' is not available

Comment: PutObjectRequest is instantiated in the sample: https://github.com/oracle/oci-java-sdk/blob/master/bmc-examples/src/main/java/UploadObjectExample.java#L58

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please test curl -v https://objectstorage.us-ashburn-1.oraclecloud.com from the same machine where the Java client times out, just to make sure there are no connection issues. If it works fine you may try to change the timeout value in ClientConfiguration. You can see more details here: https://github.com/oracle/oci-java-sdk/issues/92

Before creating a support ticket you might also try to create a new issue on [github/oci-java-sdk](https://github.com/oracle/oci-java-sdk/issues).

Comment: So you should try to configure timeout within ClientConfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

without knowing more about the config file (I do not suggest you post it here), your home region and other elements it is very hard to help.

I would suggest you open a support ticket at https://support.oracle.com, making sure that you select the Cloud tab and the Service as "Oracle Cloud Infrastructure".

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a proxy? If so, you may need to use the OCI Java SDK [ApacheConnector](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/API/SDKDocs/javasdkconfig.htm#apache).

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with the proxy. This was resolved by using the ash7 proxy.